# Use Database cursor using pg-promise with async await

Tags: javascript, async-await, pg, database-cursor, pg-promise

Property 'read' does not exist on type 'Promise'.ts(2339)
Getting this error on the code below

```
const db = pgp(/* connection details */);

const Cursor = require('pg-cursor');

const c = await db.connect(); // manually managed connection

const text = 'SELECT * FROM my_large_table WHERE something > $1';
const values = [10];

const cursor = c.client.query(new Cursor(text, values));

cursor.read(100, (err, rows) => {
  cursor.close(() => {
    c.done(); // releasing connection
  });
  // or you can just do: cursor.close(c.done);
});
```

Please give a proper solution for this

Comment: Does the code work in JavaScript? I.e. do you need to fix the behaviour, or is it just a typescript complaint that you could `@ts-ignore`?

Comment: `const cursor = await c.client.`